# Embed Strings as a Resource

Tags: python, c, windows, string, resources

I'm writing a DLL, and I would like to, post-compilation, add some strings to it as an embedded resource.

To do that, I'm using a Python script that looks similar to the following:

```
hRes = win32api.BeginUpdateResource(myFile, 0)
win32api.UpdateResource(hRes, win32con.RT_STRING, 409, buf, 1033)
win32api.EndUpdateResource(hRes, 0)
```

And that appears to work, I can see the strings in the PE with my hex-editor.

The problem occurs when my Dll tries to use `LoadString()` to pull that string back out.

The call is something like:

```
LoadString(myDll, 409, someBuf, lenOfBuf);
```

And my program is appearing to de-reference a bad pointer in the `LoadString()` call.

Does my problem lie with how I'm adding the string, or pulling it out?  And can anyone point me towards example code that does both steps?

**Edit**: I'd prefer to use the Win32 APIs for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I just needed to use the STRINGTABLE structure instead of just dumping in raw strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually, by taking the DLL, appending the data you want to store to it, and after it a 4byte integer containing the size of the appended data in bytes.

Now, if you want to read the data, read the latest 4 bytes of the file, interpret it as an integer (watch byte order), and read that amount of bytes from the end of the file (if the amount of bytes is N you read from `END - N - 4` to `END - 4`).

Comment: That would certainly work, but I'd prefer to do it with the APIs for a number of reasons.